# The Greeks finance differentiation

Tags: calculus, finance

> The Black Scholes formula with Dividends B.S.D. is
>   C=Se^(-qT) N(d_1 )-E_P e^(-rT) N(d_2 )
>   (B.S.D.)
>   in which 
>   d_1=("ln" (S/E_P )+(r-q+σ^2/2)T)/(σ√T)
>   and
>   d_2=d_1-σ√T.
>   (i) Find the little-known Greek Xi,
>   Ξ=∂C/∂q=-TN(d_1 )Se^(-qT).
>   ii) How does the Call option price change with increasing dividend value?

I believe for part i I need to differentiate the original however I’m finding this difficult any help please

( attached an image as was unsure how to write the question) [image]

Comment: You might find it challenging because the derivatives of $d_1$ and $d_2$ are annoying. But yes, that's the correct way to do it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation